# psycopg2 insert

Tags: python, psycopg2

Выполняю эту функцию,

```
def log(log_action, message):
    try:
        cursor, connection = auth()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO log (log_action, message) VALUES(%s, %s)", (log_action, message))
        print(log_action, message)
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

запись не добавляется в таблицу но обновляется индекс primaty key, т.е. если после запуска функции выполнить чистый sql запрос, то запись добавиться не автоинкрементом к id, а с пропуском [image: пример]

Comment: Не вижу в коде вызов `commit`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо

Comment: Добавите самостоятельно ответ с commit'ом? :)

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо было сделать commit

```
cursor, connection = auth()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO log (log_action, message) VALUES(%s, %s)", (log_action, message))
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Спасибо пользователю @gil9red за ответ